# Android Images have trouble loading after firing off lots of activities?

Tags: android, image

I have a simple app that displays a series of images and infomation about those images. I've set it up so that when a user touches an image, a new activity is launched and they see more pictures and a longer text description about that image. On that screen, I've also implemented the basic gallery widget that they have here in the [Hello Gallery Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html).

My problem is that even though I'm drawing on images from the res directory (I've thrown everything in drawable-mdpi thinking that there shouldn't be a huge deal), not all of the images on the gallery portion will load. And I haven't been able to reproduce it 100%, but it seems like the more I play with my phone with this app running (lock screen, unlock screen, go to one image, go back, go to another one, hit home, etc), the more likely any picture that I've got loaded up locally display blank image placeholders, gallery or not (the text comes up fine though).

I'm using a series of imagebuttons, imageviews, and gallery widgets. Play with it enough and eventually they all come as blank, but killing everything through AdvancedTaskKiller brings it back.

Sometimes pictures in my image galleries will also be blank when I first launch my app. That's really weird. I have it set so that the layoutparams are 300 by 200 and I've pulled pictures all over the place to populate my gallery. They should just all scale differently, not fail to load entirely though.

Anybody have any ideas on these?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Slow Adapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List13.html) for the Gallery.

I recommend adopting [1](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html),[2](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html),[3](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/seamlessness.html)

Comment: I think it definitely is a memory leak thing. After a while the images on the gallery come back all restored. That makes me think the garbage collector is kicking in at some point.

This is what my code looks like:

`code`

Comment: Ok, this is what I meant to say:

I think it definitely is a memory leak thing. After a while the images on the gallery come back all restored. That makes me think the garbage collector is kicking in at some point.

This is what my code looks like:

http://pastebin.com/fBq5T2Cf

I think there are still instances of the gallery going at this point. I've tried adding in activity modifiers in the AndroidManifest.xml too (noHistory=true). Maybe it's not working for whatever reason...

Answer (score 0):

It is always hard to work with images. You have to be very careful with recycling memory that your images already used otherwise you could get into different kind of troubles.

Always try to use a good Image loading library that commonly being used by Android developers.

Most commonly used library is https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It will optimise your loading.